# WEBRTC, not working between different nets

Tags: webrtc, stun

I'm developing a simple app that uses webrtc for transmitting real-time video in one direction (one sender and one receiver). It uses socket.io and node.js for the signalling.

At this moment, it's albe to transmit real-time video when the sender and receiver are in the same net (the server is already online), but if I use mobile net or if the peers are connected in different wifis it doesn´t work.
Actually, I make a test using public library's wifi and my home wifi and when the sender was in the public wifi it worked.

The message I get in firefox when it fails is :
ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details

As I've read, webrtc uses STUN/TURN servers to solve problems with net's NATS. I have introduced urls from a STUN and a TURN server but it seems it had no effect.

This is the way I'm 'using' the STUN/TURN servers:

```
var configuration = { iceServers: [
{
    urls: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca",
    username: "xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com",
    credential: "********"
},
{
    urls: "stun:stun.callwithus.com"
}
]};
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

For both sides the same and it seems the servers are up.

So, my final question is, I need to do something else to make sure webrtc is using STUN/Turn servers when it's needed? 
Or, do you know any other possible cause for this behaviour?

Everything you know can help a lot, because i couldn't find how to use those servers.

if you need more information, please ask for it.

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was solved.
It seems that Turn server wasn't working fine. I made a trial account on xyrsis and changed the stun and turn servers and it was solved.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to listen to `pc.onicecandidate` and send each candidate over your signaling channel to the other side, where you call `pc.addIceCandidate` with it like this, if using [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter):

```
pc.addIceCandidate(candidate).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

or like this if not (older syntax):

```
pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

You can also dump the ICE candidates to see if your settings work (`srflx` = stun, `relay` = turn):

```js
var PC = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
var server = { urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" };
var pc = new PC({ iceServers: [server] });

pc.onicecandidate = e => e.candidate && console.log(e.candidate.candidate);

pc.createDataChannel("dummy");
pc.createOffer().then(d => pc.setLocalDescription(d)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

You can modify that snippet to include your turn server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Well, actually i'm listenning to onIcecandidate this way: pc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
        socket.emit('new-ice-candidate', JSON.stringify({ "candidate": evt.candidate }));
        console.log('sending candidate: ' + evt.candidate);
    };

Comment: And are you seeing any `srflx` or `relay` candidates?

Answer (score 0):

[console logs of failed comunication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E0Lj.png)

That's an example of what I get in the console. It seems srflx and relay are used, but at some point I get a null candidate, the error on screenshot is because of i'm trying to log a 'candidate' property of a null object.

Comment: The log looks fine. The null candidate just signals the end of candidates, and is normal. Btw, you shouldn't comment using an answer.